# Search and returned li element in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a ul of class items . The ul has li each of class item and different id example id1 id2 id3. We have a jquery code that select each item like below and perform action based on the selected or clicked linked.

```
 $("#main-menu .items a").each(function () {
            var url = new URL($(this).attr('href'));
            if(url.is_in(that.page_url)) {
                item = $(this).closest('.item');
            }
        });
```

Example like

```
<ul class="items">
  <li id="id1" class="item"><a href="http://example/.com/id1"></a></li>
  <li id="id2" class="item"><a href="http://example/.com/id2"></a></li>
  <li>....</li>
```

My question is what would the item from the jquery code above return? My pages are separated by language, let say i want to set a value for item in the jquery code based on my language, how would i do that and what should my item look like? I tried below.

```
$("#main-menu .items a").each(function () {
                var url = new URL($(this).attr('href'));
                if(url.is_in(that.page_url) && page.language() === 'EN' && /\/text/.test(page.url)) {
                    item = "http://example.com/id2";
                }
                else{
                   if(url.is_in(that.page_url)) {
                    item = $(this).closest('.item');
                   }
                 }
            });
```

Please where do i go wrong ? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you want to change the url of the particular item?

Comment: I want to select a particular item and set it item based on the language of the page sir. IF the page is in french and the url is or has `"/url"` example.

Comment: Hi , i have edited my code.

Comment: did you manage to get the language of the page?

Comment: Yes sir. My issue is with the item i am trying to set. What should item return and how should i set it? I am setting it to a complete url

Comment: you want something like this?https://jsfiddle.net/n32bxhzb/5/